# Как правильно использовать Update или Start в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Unity я новичок и уже делал игры, и они получались, но тут не давно стало интересно, а правильно ли я все пишу? Меня интересует, как правильно использовать Update? Я делал так: для каждого объекта крепил скрипт, и прописывал ему что-то в Update, например в скрипте Coin, указывал в Update, что coin должен вращаться, а в другом скрипте, например Stack указывал, что палка должна двигаться по другому, и так ко всему, и в проекте было около 10 скриптов которые выполняют что-то в Update для отдельного объекта.

Главный вопрос:, правильно ли это? А может нужно делать по-другому? Например, выделить отдельный скрипт там где будет этот Update, инициализировать все классы в этот скрипт, и все прописать в 1 Update.

Или может нужно делать как то по-другому? Что вы посоветуете?

Comment: "Правильного" способа скорее всего нет, скорее есть общепринятые практики. Советую заглянуть на гитхаб в проекты на юнити https://github.com/Unity3D-Projects

Comment: Еще под большим вопросом как именно ты вращал обьекты, где ты использовал  GetComponent<>() и много других вопросов. Вобщем, даный вопрос слишком общий и размытый. Налажать можно много где. Но! Если результат удовлетворял твои потребности и не создавал тебе проблем при развитии проэкта (тормоза в игровом процессе или сложности в обслуживании и развити кода) - то глубоко пофиг какие ошибки там внутри. Главное что результат именно тот, который нужен.

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Был ли при этом полезен ответ данный ниже? Если да, отметьте его принятым. Галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: @aepot похоже многие почему-то не думают о такой возможности. Либо ответ был получен - вопрос забыт, либо вопрос просто был забыт, а ответ IShark был не особо нужен...

Comment: @МаксимФисман да просто правила ресурса никто не читает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Выделить отдельный скрипт там где будет этот Update, инициализировать все классы в этот скрипт, и все прописать в 1 Update.

Ух-х, мурашки по коже пробежали. Прямо фильм ужасов.

---

Update срабатывает автоматически каждый кадр. Каждый скрипт должен отвечать за определенные характеристики определенного объекта. Например, скрипт монетки должен содержать стоимость монетки, контроль анимации-вращения (хотя я бы это сделал анимацией), подбор монетки, когда на нее наступает игрок и т.п. Скрипт монетки не может отвечать за, например, вычисление скорости бега персонажа при двойном прыжке через 35-й пень на 4-м уровне при средней сложности.

Также и предложенный вами вариант: 1 скрипт не может отвечать за Update всех объектов, хотя бы потому, что в скрипте всех объектов есть собственные переменные, с которыми надо работать: брать значения, изменять его, - есть другие компоненты, которые надо периодически изменять...

10 скриптов для одного проекта - крайне мало.  Так мало скриптов бывает только в обучающих видео на ютубе. В нормальных проектах число скриптов может начинаться с 0 и стартовать  `to infinity and beyond` с третьей космической скоростью. Ничего страшного в том, что у вас на сцене 10 объектов со скриптов с Update, который выполняет несколько строчек кода - нет (если там, конечно, нет цикла на пару миллионов итераций).

Если в вашей игре не FPS не проседает до -10 (шутка, порогово низкий нормальный [FPS](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5c79360c5f18a600b90a79a2/kakoi-samyi-luchshii-fps-dlia-igr-5c82ba9166134c00b3f55f49) - 30, а заикание наблюдается при FPS ниже 20), то нормально все. [Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) в принципе предназначен для выполнения работы, которая ДОЛЖНА выполняться в каждом кадре. Хотя, как нам пишут глубокоуважаемые разработчики Unity, не в каждом скрипте Update() обязан присутствовать и требуется.

Comment: Если мой ответ был вам полезен, примите его, поставив галочку